# Dynamically adding in-memory QgsVectorLayer triggers a popup in the UI - how to eliminate

Tags: qgis, python

I use this function to create layers that display results to my queries. However a dialog always pops up asking me to confirm the crs. Is it possible to suppress this ?

```
    def addResultLayer(name, feature, symbol, groupname):
        res_abs_path = self.getStubVectorFile()
        result_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", name, "memory")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(result_layer, False)
        result_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
        result_layer.rendererV2().setSymbol(symbol)
        result_node = QgsLayerTreeLayer(result_layer)
        self.findGroup(groupname).insertChildNode(0, result_node)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide CRS, for example:

```
result_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", name, "memory")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot provide a CRS for new layers, as Azimo suggests, then change

**Settings -> Options -> CRS**

You can specify if new layers without CRS get projects CRS, a default one, or from user input. This is valid for at least QGIS version 2.8.7.